# Click event on DIV button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a DIV element that I am using as a javascript button. It works fine unless I click on a certain area, then the click event is not triggered at all. This seems to only be an issue in Chrome.

HTML

```
<div class="button">Close</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    $debug.html('Clicked: ' + currentDate.getMinutes() + ':' + currentDate.getSeconds() + ':' + currentDate.getMilliseconds());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cellenburg/uwGK4/

Clicking anywhere on the button works fine unless you click exactly where the text begins on the left. In the case of my fiddle, click on the left side of the letter "C". You'll see that the event doesn't fire. Although this is a small area, it seems that I click it almost every time.

I have tried everything. I'm guessing it's just a problem with the text node accepting the click and it's not propagating to it's parent? Any ideas how I might work around this issue?

Comment: Cannot reproduce that on Mac/Chrome - what are you using ?

Comment: Which version of Chrome is experiencing the problem? I'm running 25.0.1364.68 beta-m and the clicks are firing for me, regardless of the mouse position next to the 'C'.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it on Win7/Chrome.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this by clicking on "C", just under the top curve.

Comment: "Any ideas how I might work around this issue?" yeah, use a button instead of a div.

Comment: @j08691 - I have icons in some of my buttons. Using an input or button tag was giving me too many issues, so I decided to go this route. I may have to revisit though.

Comment: @j08691 - the `button` tag gives me the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears to be an "attempt" to select the text.

Add this to your CSS:

```
body {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Fiddle update worked in chrome for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/uwGK4/1/

Also just a thought.  You can change it from body to what ever to just prevent your "button" text from being selectable.

Updated:

Tell me if you can break this!  I haven't been able too.  Basicly I removed padding, declared hieght and width, wrapped the Close in a `<div>` with a class called `.label` and set its margins.

http://jsfiddle.net/uwGK4/5/

New JS:

```
.label{
    margin: 5px;
}
```

New HTML:

```
<div class="button"><div class="label">Close</div></div>
```

Removed padding CSS from `.button` and `.button:active`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I used the `unselectable="on"` attribute for IE.

Comment: Any time, like your button by the way :)

Comment: Spoke too soon. Actually it doesn't work. Ugh! Any other ideas?

Comment: Weird, works for me(and I was able to duplicate it before hand)... what OS and browser version you on? You may have to tweek the CSS from `body` to maybe `.button`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to fix it. (I would recommend doing this anyway though, so people don't get annoying text highlighting when the click certain places on the button.)

Comment: Guys thanks for you help on this. I may just revert back to trying to make the `button` tag work.

Comment: `button` tag gives same result. @defaultNINJA - I'm running WIN 7/64 Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m

Comment: @ChrisEllenburg I haven't given up, trying a few things.  Even wrote a jQuery script to attach same event to child elements and it didn't help...

Comment: Well it's ugly, but I found a work-around. I added a `span` inside the button as sort of a target layer on top of the text. http://jsfiddle.net/cellenburg/uwGK4/4/

Comment: @ChrisEllenburg LOL! I guess I should have checked back earlier.  Let me know if you liked what I changed.  I did sort of the same thing, but removed all padding and wrapped the label in div and set its margins instead which seems to have worked.

Comment: @defaultNINJA - Looks like we basically came up with the same solution. Thanks a lot for your help on this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24929/discussion-between-chris-ellenburg-and-defaultninja)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the padding change from the :active event. I think moving the start of the text while you're clicking down on it is causing some weird behavior. I do admit it changes the appearance of the button, which is kind of lame.

Also, try making the padding really high (like `padding:60px 90px 40px 110px;`). You should see that clicking anywhere on the text itself seems to treat it more like a drag action than a click action.

By the way, this happens in Safari for windows too, so I'm guessing it's a WebKit thing.

Might be worth filing a bug report.

Comment: Thanks parKing. I think it must be a bug also. It even happens when using a `button` tag. I ended up positioning an extra element over the text. http://jsfiddle.net/cellenburg/uwGK4/4/

Comment: That's another way to approach it. It's too bad we have to do things like this.